# Disappearing Dock in OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dock

I have Parallels desktop for my Windows programs. Yesterday when closing Windows (XP) my dock disappeared from the bottom of my screen. I've tried various remedies including two different modification softwares that restore the dock and since then it will appear occasionally.

I tried to quit Dock via *Activity Monitor* too, but it flashes in and out and a few times I've been able to grab it and press *quit* or *force quit*, nothing happens.

Anyone have any ideas about how to solve this problem? I have rebooted, logged off and on etc. all to no avail. Then suddenly in the middle of an application it will appear bigger and bolder than ever!

Comment: Just to make sure, you've tried pressing Command+Option+D to try and un-hide the dock, just in case you've accidentally hidden it, right?

Comment: This sounds like your Dock is repeatedly launching and crashing. If you minimize a window (green button), does it immediately pop back up? When the Dock crashes, all windows are unminimized.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has to do with parallels tools. If you uninstall them the dock should become stable. Still parallels will become pretty much useless and unable to communicate with macOSx.